# moq does not return what I defined in mock.Setup

Tags: c#, moq

I am mocking a function in c# using Moq.

```
 public void Mapper_GetProductMappingTest()
    {
        //Arrange:
        Mapping mapping= new Mapping()
        {
            code = "AB"
        };
        Mapper mapper = new Mapper(new MongoStore());

        CaseProduct caseProduct = new CaseProduct()
        {
            ProductID = "ABC",

        };
        Mock<Mapper> mock = new Mock<Mapper>(new MongoStore());
        mock.Setup(x => x.GetMapping(caseProduct)).Returns(mapping);
        // why does it return the caseproduct not the mapping?!
        var mapped = mock.Object.GetMapping(caseProduct);
        Assert.IsTrue(mapped.code == "AB");
```

This Assert.IsTrue is failed and the mock.Object.GetMapping(caseProduct) returns ABC insteadof AB.
Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Does `Mapper.GetMapping` have `virtual` modifier? Also, please try if `mock.Setup(x => x.GetMapping(It.IsAny<CaseProduct>())).Returns(mapping)` works as you'd expect. It will match any call to GetMapping, so it should work and we'll see if that's something with your code or Moq.

Comment: Yes, it is virtual and also I tried mock.Setup(x =>    x.GetMapping(It.IsAny<CaseProduct>())).Returns(mapping) still have the same problem.

Comment: It is weird. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I get the error saying that the ProductID is not found.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a problem with Moq if you are getting the ProductID of caseProduct returned instead of the value set in the constructor of Mapping

Comment: but shouldn't it return the value specified in .Retruns()?

Comment: Which version of Moq do you curenty have? Do you have latest version?

Comment: My version of Moq is 4.2.1408.717. With this version the ```mock``` works correctly and returns the fake ```mapping``` object.

Comment: Let's figure this out step by step. Firstly, your test does not need the "mapper" object. Remove that line of code so that other users can concentrate on the real problem. Secondly, are you saying if you change the "code" property of CaseProduct to lets say "this should not be returned", the mock will continue returning the new string? Thirdly, any specific observations while debugging the code? Is the control going inside any concrete implementations?

Comment: Does it have to be the setup that is incorrect? If something returns the input value I would say that your implementation has a bug and that you need to fix that. That is, you are returning the input value, not the value returned from GetMapping(). Your setup looks fine to me. (I am assuming that you have ommited the method you want to test).